# Flash can't show Azerbaijan characters

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts

I'm developing application on Azerbaijan Language(in flash cs5 on actionscript 3), when I copy symbols from word document to flash it shows only the letters which are same in Latin. For example in "fəallıq göstəricisi" flash converts second and 13th symbols(both are "ə") to rectangles. What is a problem and how to fix? I'm using Sylfaen font at the moment.

Comment: Solved: changed this characters from font's character map.

Answer (score 1):

The file being loaded should be saved with UTF-8 encoding did you try it?

Comment: Solved: changed this characters from font's character map.